# Why does my line show up as a green dot near Africa?

Tags: openlayers

Snippet which demonstrates the problem:

```js
let coordinates = [
  [-82, 42],
  [10, 45]
];

const myFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates),
  name: "Line"
});

myFeature.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({ stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "green", width: 8 }) })
);

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [myFeature]
});

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
  })
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 512px;
  width: 2424px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

The coordinate [-82, 42] is inside of the US. [10, 45] is in Italy.

What is rendered is a small line (looks like a green dot) near Africa.

What did I do wrong? I am using OpenLayers 7.1.0.

[image: rendering]

Comment: Those are close to where the prime meridian intersects the equator, so probably a unit interpretation issue?

Comment: @LeviRamsey I changed the coordinates to [-82, 10] and [10, 65], but behavior did not change. If you would like to suggest specific coordinates to try, I can.

Comment: But reading a bit further in the FAQ, it seems, that the map per default uses WebMercator coordinates (which is a metric projection) and not lat/long. Means, that `[10, 45]` actually is "10 **meters** east and 45 **meters** north from the center of the map" (instead of degrees). Ie you need to convert your long/lat values to WebMercator with `fromLonLat`

Comment: @derpirscher Bingo. That was it.

Comment: You can also set the projection of the view to EPSG 4326 like this: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/epsg-4326.html

Comment: @BR75 confirmed, that works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer came from two questions in the OpenLayers FAQ.

1. [Why is my map centered on the gulf of guinea (or africa, the ocean, null-island)?](https://openlayers.org/doc/faq.html#why-is-my-map-centered-on-the-gulf-of-guinea-or-africa-the-ocean-null-island-)
2. [Why is the order of a coordinate [lon,lat], and not [lat,lon]?](https://openlayers.org/doc/faq.html#why-is-the-order-of-a-coordinate-lon-lat-and-not-lat-lon-)

The coordinates need to be projected into Web Mercator, which can be done easily using the `ol.proj.fromLonLat` function.

```js
let coordinates = [
  ol.proj.fromLonLat( [-82, 42] ),
  ol.proj.fromLonLat( [10, 45] )
];
            
const myFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates),
  name: "Line"
});

myFeature.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({ stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "green", width: 8 }) })
);

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [myFeature]
});

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
  })
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 512px;
  width: 2424px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

The other option is to change the projection of the view to EPSG:4326. Then, the lon, lat coordinates can be used without conversion.

```js
let coordinates = [
  [-82, 42],
  [10, 45]
];
            
const myFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates),
  name: "Line"
});

myFeature.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({ stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "green", width: 8 }) })
);

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [myFeature]
});

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
  })
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 512px;
  width: 2424px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the 2 options listed by @Eric G there is a third option, to call `ol.proj.useGeographic()` at the start of the application so all coordinates are treated as lon, lat.

```js
ol.proj.useGeographic();

let coordinates = [
  [-82, 42],
  [10, 45]
];
            
const myFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates),
  name: "Line"
});

myFeature.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({ stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "green", width: 8 }) })
);

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [myFeature]
});

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
  })
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 512px;
  width: 2424px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```